# В Pycharm не импортируется модуль

Tags: python, pycharm

Для проекта требуется модуль **glfw**, который у меня ранее был скачан. Однако при попытке запустить код в *Pycharm* получаю ошибку с уведомлением об отсутствии библиотеки.

Стандартный способ скачать через *Settings* не помог - получил ошибку (см. изображение).

[image: Ошибка при попытке загрузить модуль]

Попробовал скачать модуль через `pip install` непосредственно в папку с проектом. Однако получил уведомление

> Requirement already satisfied: glfw in c:\users\

Comment: Какой интерпретатор в проекте стоит, системный или virtualenv? Судя по ошибке ищет в python установленным под юзером, но если в системе что-то намурычено с UAC, но из под cmd, возможно, ставите под админом.

Comment: Спасибо за идею: добавил в виртуальное окружение библиотеку - и все получилось.

Comment: Правда, следом получил ошибку для другой библиотеки pyrr: `Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xea in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 7)
    Running from numpy source directory`.

Comment: Причем ошибка из-за numpy - попробовал обойти библиотеку pyrr, однако с numpy та же ошибка

Comment: Это уже совсем другая ошибка. Попробуйте различные версии numpy поставить или грузануть напрямую с GH. У меня с numpy не было никогда проблем.